# Как организовать scroll для label?

Tags: .net, c++

Добрый вечер!

Понадобилось в label прокручивать текст. Достал label, vscroll, соединил на формочке в 10-й студии, погуглил и абсолютно ничего полезного не нашел. Я новичек в этом деле, не так часто сталкивался с такими штучками. Как быть? Может для этого не label нужно использовать? Нужно учесть, что через какое-то время в label может дописываться текст...

Comment: а вы вообще уверены, что вам действительно надо прокручивать текст в Label? C точки зрения пользователя это наверняка будет выглядеть по-уродски.

Comment: Я предполагал "Может для этого не label нужно использовать?" А какие средства существуют для этого?

Comment: Ставите на форму edit (или как он там называется), делаете многострочным, с серым фоном (на самом деле правильно делать не с gray,  а там есть специальный цвет - цвет окна). Теперь мелочи остались - убрать border.

Comment: и еще курсор при наведении на этот edit стоит сделать обычной стрелкой

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под edit? Какой компонент? Edit, не нашел такого...

Comment: редактируемое текстовое поле

Comment: Спасибо всем! Нашел такую штуку richTextBox1, вроде как подходит...)

Comment: TextBox
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.textbox.aspx

Comment: Используйте [TextBox][1] с ReadOnly = true  
  [1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.textbox(v=vs.90).aspx